# Custom Function addition in crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, custom-fields

I have to format a date string to a custom format like i need to convert "11/04/2016" to "11/D/2016". simply I have to replace the month number that is here 04 to an alphabet with the same sequence like 01 will be replaced by A and 02 by B and so on. I don't have any problem for writing logic for general purpose programming language. But I dont know how to add this custom functionality in crystal report. 
I have checked formula fields but it seems they have predefined formulas whereas I need custom formula.
Is there any way to add custom function in crystal report and pass it some parameter and then it returns you come data that you show on the report ???
Thanks in advance !

Comment: since you have the syntax.. check this link on how to use custom functions http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic420.html%23id_2006123114004d3207e2_437

Comment: Actually I dont know the syntax. I am new to the crystal report. I have checked the link youshared but i got nothing in that. or may be i wasn't able to understand.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more please ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Report --> formula workshop` and there go to `New` and there select `custom function`

Syntax would be:

Create a function `Convert`

```
Function(StringVar value) //this will take the input string

//Here write your logic and return a value.and close the function
```

Now you have created a custom function.

To use this create a new formula in functions go to custom functions and double click already create function

```
Convert("11/04/2016"); //close the window and place formula on design and refresh you get required output
```